# Including a java class method in jsp file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

i am trying to use function which is in java class( getInfo() )

```
package classe_j;
public class testh {
public static String getInfo(){
return"get Info"; } }
```

and use it in jsp file as the following

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="classe_j.*"%>
..........
<th><%=testh.getInfo() %></th>
```

i got no errors but when run it i got `SystemError`
[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: please share the exception/error stack.

Comment: I advise you not to do this.  It's a very bad idea to use scriptlet code in JSPs.  That's a 90s era idea that has fallen out of favor.  Your tags say you're using Spring MVC.  You should add that class to the model map and pass it down to the JSP.  No scriptlets.